# How can I stop this syntax error in Python?

Tags: python

For this block of code, the second line consistently shows a syntax error, even though I think that everything has been done right:

```
@client.event
async def on_message():
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The full error message please!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To get a good answer, you will need to include the entire error you're getting — and preferably a [mre].

Comment: `on_message` takes a parameter, you should be using `async def on_message(message):`, other than that, looks fine. I imagine the error you're getting is actually a `NameError`.

Comment: Maybe you're running it with Python 2 by accident? `async def` would be invalid.

Answer (score 1):

The `discord.py` event reference [`on_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message) takes one parameters, `message`:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
```

As a side note, be sure to always check the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#).

Answer (score 0):

The `on_message` event for Discord.py passes the `message` object which contains a reference to the message itself that triggered the event, in order to manipulate anything with this as you are doing, you need to include this parameter in your event handler function.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
```

**Relevant Documentation:** https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message